# Finding First Row in a RDLC Table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, rdlc

I have a table in a RDLC report which is utilized as a subreport, and the first column of this table is a static string. Does anyone know how I can determine if a row is the first in the table.  I tried using "=First("My String")" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate functions work with "Scope', referring to the paragraph scope in this MSDN article, might help...

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms252112(VS.80).aspx"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms252112(VS.80).aspx)

From what I understand you may have to define a scope or try =First("MyString", Nothing).

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the link supplied by [ThatBloke in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103240/finding-first-row-in-a-rdlc-table#103388), I found the RowNumber command.

Which means that this worked:

```
=IIf(RowNumber(Nothing)=1,"myString", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

=IIF((RowNumber(Nothing) Mod <>)=0)

<> Indicate No of Rows Which you want To Display